# Error ERR 212 Not enough global stack al compilar

Tags: genexus

En una KB GXEvo3 U12, generador .NET con Framework 3.5, de aproximadamente 40.000 objetos, durante la compilación aparece un errorr "**ERR 212 Not enough global stack**", el cual se visualiza en el OutPut del IDE, lo que hace cancelar la compilación.

Se encontró una solución parcial que consiste en, dirigirse dentro del directorio web del modelo y allí dentro eliminar o renombrar el archivo GXHPRO15.002 y volver a especificar algún objeto.

El archivo GXHPRO15.002, es un listado de objetos que están incluidos en la KB. Por eso, al renombrarlo o eliminarlo, hay objetos que no se encuentran incluidos en el nuevo porque estaban en el anterior que fue modificado.

¿Existe alguna mejor solución para evitar el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es crear un archivo llamado MSBuild.env en la carpeta raíz de la KB o en C:\Windows, miren este SAC:
https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=54119;;

Answer (score 0):

El error es porque un stack de prolog (lenguaje de AI utilizado en varios algoritmos de Genexus, ejemplo: especificación, generación, etc) se va de "rango".
En versiones posteriores de Genexus se han ido mejorando esos algoritmos (ejemplo: https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=46234)

De todos modos, en KBs grandes (como el tuyo) no sé si en versiones posteriores ayudará.

Algo que puede afectar (por lo que decís del 002 que eliminas) es la generación de DeveloperMenu. Eso lo podés verificar fácilmente configurando que no lo genere (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8940,Generate+developer+menu+makefile+property) y haciendo un "build".

Esto se da especialmente en KBs que tienen muchos objetos mains u objetos SOAP, REST, etc.